# for YOUR information & for YOU information?

Tags: for, acronyms

Why don't we interpret **FYI** as “information for you” or “for-you information”? As a matter of fact, I don't understand the **“for your”** in **FYI**.

P.S. I've already checked the dictionary before asking. So my focus is not quite on the history of the acronym, but how to understand the idiom (because I don't have a good feel of English).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP seems to have a problem with basic idiomatic fixed phrases.

Comment: @Yuri Isn't this a Q&A site for English learners?

Comment: By that, I mean instead of just accepting what is common and has been inserted in dictionaries the OP's trying to change it into what he thinks is true. Actually there is no answer to such questions. Read the answer below for instance. It didn't really answer the OP's question! It just repeated what dictionaries say about FYI.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question with more details. Also I had given suggestion to the answer below for why its citation is distracting. It did answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI = "For Your Information" as in, "Here is information for you" (to add to the information that you have).

> "FYI" is commonly used in e-mail, instant messaging or memo and
>   messages, typically in the message subject, to flag the message as an
>   informational message, with the intent to communicate to the receiver
>   that he/she may be interested in the topic, but is not required to
>   perform any action. It is also commonly used in informal and business
>   spoken conversations.  <sup>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FYI))</sup>

Comment: Still, why is it “for your” instead of “for you”? :-|

Comment: It's an abbreviation that has always meant "For Your Information" -- which does make sense just like this example:  If it's your birthday and I get you a gift, it is "For your birthday", not "For you, birthday".  A toothbrush is "for your teeth" not "for-you teeth".  I suppose an explanation is that "for your" is adding something to a collection that you have (like _your teeth_, or _things_ you get for _your birthday_, or the "collection of information" that you have in _your memory_.    Your  example of "for-you birthday" is incorrect usage of a hyphen and would never be used.

Comment: (I'm enjoying answering these questions because even with recent college-level English upgrading, I'm surprised how many of the questions really make me think "why _do_ we say it that way?"  :-)  Unfortunately for those learning English as a second language, there are **a lot** of weird rules that make _no_ logical sense.)  :-/

Comment: One more subtle point related to this phrase - "For your Information" can be spoken in a condescending tone to someone.  "Well!  For Your Information... I AM An Expert In Decorative Design!!!  Humph!"  And in this case, it is a verbal battering ram.  I admit that when I see FYI, I get a slight taste of this attitude.

Comment: @ashleedawg Ah, I see what you mean now. The cited source is distracting. The analogy to *for your birthday* is very useful. This reminds me of *for your reference*. One of my dictionary has *for information/reference*. What makes me confused (and you too?) is that I think we don't *own* information, only know of it.

Comment: @K-K I consider information owned!  I made a copy of some of my information and now you own it too.  :)   (...which kind of reinforces Michael's point!)    ...  **Check [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/who-owns-information-he-world-latam-banking-outlook-2016-vadym-danko/) out**.